# Prolog return list of free days

Tags: prolog

I have a question (again :)). let assume we have the following data:
the first number is the day second the month and third the event

```
day(1,1, 'New Year')
day(1,1, 'The day after the new year')
day(23,1, 'The day i will finally understand this language :)')
day(14,2, 'Valentin's day')
day(16,2, 'Family day')
day(22,2, 'hein.. dont now lol')

nday(1,31).
nday(2,28).
nday(3,31).
nday(4,30).
nday(5,31).
```

I'm asked to create a predicate such that given a `Day`, it returns a month (only if the given day do not have event. for instance `freeDay(23,X)`. `X` should have the value 2. if `X` equals 4, it should holds 1 (and if we enter the semi colon, it will return 2 since day 4 doesn't have any event in February as well. i have many more data. So i did the following but i get the value 0.

```
freeDay(_, Month,0):-  Month > 12, !.
freeDay(X,Answer):- freeDay(X, 1, Answer).

freeDay(Day, Month,X):-
    day(Day, Month,_),
    W is Month + 1,
    freeDay(Day, W, X).

freeDay(Day, Month, X):-
           W is Month +1,
        freeDay(Day,W, X).
```

Can you tell me what i did wrong please??

Comment: No one to help me tonight ? :(

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean by, for example, *if `X` equals 4, it should holds 1*. And I'm unsure what you mean about the semicolon.

Comment: If X has the value 4 we should return 1, because in january there is no event on that date

Comment: forget about the semicolon i wasn't clear enough!

Comment: in other word, for a given Day i should return the month from which that day does not have an event, dont know if it's more clear :(

Comment: Actually i know what you mean by the semicolon now. :) What did you query that gave you `0`?

Comment: freeDay(27,X). pretty much any number i enter lol

Comment: You should do a trace. It will show you what's happening. But the short answer is that your `freeDay` keeps recursing if the day doesn't exist until it encounters, `freeDay(_, Month, 0)`. So the second argument comes back `0`. And if the day exists, it does the same thing: it keeps recursing until `Month` is greater than 12 and finally sets the second argument to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

What your code does:

1. By calling `freeDay(23,X)`, `freeDay(X,Answer)` succeds which calls the `freeDay(X, 1, Answer)`.
2. Prolog first checks which of the predicates can be executed with the current inputs.
3. It finds out that `freeDay(_, Month,0):-  Month > 12, !.` is not applicable since the month is 1 and it moves to the next predicate.
4. `freeDay(Day, Month,X)` is applicable, and what it does is increasing the month and calling itself(recursion).
5. The month keeps increasing when finally is more than 12. Remember everytime a predicate is called prolog checks the first predicate that it is applicable. Therefore this time `freeDay(_, Month,0):-  Month > 12, !` succeeds.
6. `freeDay(_, Month,0):- Month > 12, !.` breaks the loop (recursion) by the use of the cut annotation `!` and returns the Answer which is 0 in this case. (In plain english here you say no matter what day is if month is greater than 12 return 0. This is the last statement executed.)

I hope you understand what's wrong. Generally logic programming requires **thinking outside of the box**. You need **first** to **understand** the problem and **then** attempt to **solve** it, in a simplistic way.

Comment: Ya i understand My mistake, i try to make it fail when there is no event for the given Day, so it will attempt  the last predicate

Comment: @ApexPredator No this is not the mistake. The mistake is that your freeDay predicates, all they do no matter the input is to increase the month and eventually, the break point predicate takes place and returns 0. First try to understand the problem, the solution is pretty straight forward.

Comment: My bad for the last predicate i had this freeDay(Day, Month, Month):-
           W is Month +1,
        freeDay(Day,W, Month).

Comment: straight forward for a newbie? i feel dumb then because i have been working on this for hours

Comment: As I said, try to understand the problem. You are not approaching the problem the correct way. For example, the problem is related with finding a month for a day that it is not in your database. This implies that the given day 'freeDay(Day, Month,X)' can not be the same with the 'day(Day, Month,_)'. Because if the latter predicate is true, then it is not what you are looking for. No recursion is needed to solve this problem, begin with excluding an instance of the month that you are not looking for like this 'freeDay(Day, Month):-
    day(X, Month,_),
    Day \= X.'

Comment: Later on figure out, how to exclude all the instances of the month that you are not looking for (maybe with a list and a member() predicate) and also identify how to get the results only once. There is no reason to feel dumb, I have spend hours and hours in prolog myself, when I finally understood that the problem is more important to understand and break into small pieces, then everything is simple. Please mark the answer as correct if it answers your question so for the thread to close.

Comment: Ya thanks soo much, really did approach it in the Wrong way! worked hours on this i will finish it tomorrow since i know how WRONG i was. thanks again man

Comment: @ApexPredator you ask, in your question, I cite, "Can you tell me what i did wrong please??" (original spelling). You got a detailed answer, plus further explanation in the comments that tell you what you did wrong. And yet, I feel unnecessary sarcasm in your last comment. I hope I am mistaken.

Comment: you are mistaken!! i wouldn't had posted anything here if i hadn't tried myself, not every one is born genius sorry

Comment: you can see that i was trying to solve it in the wrong way which took me hours